# Including a servlet in a JSP file

Tags: jsp, servlets, jspinclude

I started a Dynamic Web project in Eclipse and the Automatically generated directory is:

```
Java Resources
|-src
|  |-myPackage
|     |-.java files
|-libraries
Build
Web Content
|-META-INF
|-WEB-INF
|-index.jsp
```

In my index.jsp file I include a servlet:

`<jsp:include page="ServletName" flush="true">`

that is a java file placed under JavaResources/src/myPackage, but i get an error because that file is supposed to be placed under Web Content. How can I change the expected path?
Thank you.

Comment: Is the servlet configured in web.xml?

Comment: no but I used the @webservlet annotation

Answer (score 0):

The page attribute is supposed to be the path of a resource of your webapp. A resource can be a static resource, a JSP, or the path of a servlet of your webapp. It has nothing to do with the name of the java file of your servlet. See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro8.html.

So, if your servlet is mapped to `/foo` (thanks to the `@WebServlet` annotation, or to the `servlet-mapping` element in the web.xml), then you should use /foo as the value of he page attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't have a web.xml file but I have the annotation @WebServlet. I use it as value but i get that error.

Comment: I solved the problem changing the error to a warning, then the class is found using the annotation.